# Couchbase server allowing concurrent document mutation, even with CAS set?

Tags: java, couchbase, concurrentmodification

I have an object, SomeObject, which represents an object stored as a document in Couchbase. SomeObject has a cas variable for containing the CAS value.

I have code like this:

```
/* Get two identical objects from Couchbase, they'll have identical CAS value */
SomeObject someObjectA = getSomeObjectFromCouchbase(sameId);
SomeObject someObjectB = getSomeObjectFromCouchbase(sameId);

/* Make arbitrary modifications to the objects */
someObjectA.getListInObject().add(arbitraryValue1);
someObjectB.getListInObject().add(arbitraryValue2);

/* Convert SomeObject objects to JsonDocument objects, ensuring the CAS value is set */
JsonDocument jsonDocA = JsonDocument.create(someObjectA.getId(), JsonObject.fromJson(mapper.writeValueAsString(someObjectA)), someObjectA.getCas());
JsonDocument jsonDocB = JsonDocument.create(someObjectB.getId(), JsonObject.fromJson(mapper.writeValueAsString(someObjectB)), someObjectB.getCas());

/* Perform upserts on both JsonDocument objects; expectation is the second one should fail with CASMismatchException because the CAS value should have changed after the first upsert */
couchbaseDao.getDatasource().getBucket().upsert(jsonDocA, writeTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
couchbaseDao.getDatasource().getBucket().upsert(jsonDocB, writeTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

Despite my expectation that the second upsert should fail with CASMismatchException, which I attempt to catch by wrapping the code in a try/catch block, it does not happen.  Both upserts succeed, and the server does indeed change the CAS value after both upserts.  It's as if it's not even checking the CAS value upon upsert, just blindly accepting anything and then updating the CAS value.

The end result is that the list in the Couchbase document only contains arbitraryValue2, and is missing arbitraryValue1, whereas I expected it to have arbitraryValue1 and not arbitraryValue2 (as the second upsert should have thrown CASMismatchException). Am I doing something wrong, or is something wrong with the server such that it is not dealing with CAS properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

CAS is just used in the **replace** method:

```
    JsonDocument doc = userRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().get("1");
    JsonDocument doc2 = userRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().get("1");
    doc.content().put("username", "Michael");

    userRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().replace(doc);

    doc2.content().put("username", "denis");
    userRepository.getCouchbaseOperations().getCouchbaseBucket().replace(doc2);

    User userResult2 = userRepository.findById("1").get();
    System.out.println(userResult2.getUsername());
```

If you try to execute the code above you will get the following exception:

```
aused by: com.couchbase.client.java.error.CASMismatchException: null
at com.couchbase.client.java.bucket.api.Mutate$3$1.call(Mutate.java:333) ~[java-client-2.7.11.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.java.bucket.api.Mutate$3$1.call(Mutate.java:308) ~[java-client-2.7.11.jar:na]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.observers.Subscribers$5.onNext(Subscribers.java:235) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeDoOnEach$DoOnEachSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeDoOnEach.java:101) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.producers.SingleProducer.request(SingleProducer.java:65) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.producers.ProducerArbiter.setProducer(ProducerArbiter.java:126) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback$TimeoutMainSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeTimeoutTimedWithFallback.java:155) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.setProducer(OnSubscribeMap.java:102) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.Subscriber.setProducer(Subscriber.java:205) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at rx.subjects.AsyncSubject.onCompleted(AsyncSubject.java:103) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.completeResponse(AbstractGenericHandler.java:508) ~[core-io-1.7.11.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler.access$000(AbstractGenericHandler.java:86) ~[core-io-1.7.11.jar:na]
at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.AbstractGenericHandler$1.call(AbstractGenericHandler.java:526) ~[core-io-1.7.11.jar:na]
at rx.internal.schedulers.ScheduledAction.run(ScheduledAction.java:55) ~[rxjava-1.3.8.jar:1.3.8]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:835) ~[na:na]
Caused by: rx.exceptions.OnErrorThrowable$OnNextValue: OnError while emitting onNext value: com.couchbase.client.core.message.kv.ReplaceResponse.class
```

Answer (score 0):

For the GO users here, I am using upsertSpec with CAS to figure out any parallel mutation on the doc. It does seem to work pretty well for me. Not sure about the java SDK though, Ideally behavior should be the same irrespective of language.